# How To Set/Update user profile custom property value programmatically?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, user-accounts

Currently created User Profile Custom Property "Function" programmatically,But I Don't Know How To assign Value To That Custom Property programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that like you would with a custom column on a list. You instantiate the `UserProfileManager`, and then you can either loop through each "Profile" or you can get a specific profile and set the property.

Example iterating through each:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://contoso.com")
{
    var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    var userProfiles = profileManager.GetEnumerator();

    while (userProfiles.MoveNext())
    {
        var userProfile = (UserProfile)userProfiles.Current;
        userProfile["MyCustomField"].Value = "Some value";
        userProfile.Commit(); // Might be update, can't remember.
    }
}
```

Example taking a single user profile and updating it:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://contoso.com")
{
    var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
    var userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\username");
    userProfile["MyCustomField"].Value = "Some value";
    userProfile.Commit(); // Might be update, can't remember.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it for example via PowerShell (sorry, I don't know which language do you really need):

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$site = Get-SPSite http://YourSiteCollection
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site            

$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("user@company.com");
$userProfile["Function"].Value = "Value you would like to set"   
$userProfile.Commit()
```

You might find [this reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20692.sharepoint-2013-get-set-and-copy-user-profile-properties-using-powershell.aspx) useful.